# Setting up connection to the origin server resource on specific port through AWS Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a site that works with AWS Cloudfront, but I have a trouble with connection to the one web application that works on custom port (not on 80 or 443). From the origin domain name my web application are accessible but from domain that connected to the Cloudfront I can't get access to it. I tried to add aditional origin resource on distribution setting but that didn't resolve this issue and I couldn't connect to this application. Is it possible to set up Cloudfront distribution that will forward connection from, for example, https://origin.example.com:8080 to https://example.com:8080?

Answer (score 2):

CloudFront can be configured to connect to the origin server on most ports.

> Valid values include ports 80, 443, and 1024 to 65535.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDomainName

...but CloudFront will only *listen* for requests on port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS.  This can't be configured.  Applications connecting to CloudFront have to use the standard ports.