# Disable 80 port for our aws serverless app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have app built on AWS with S3 and Cloudfront. Company's security team require us to disable 80 port for our app.

Notes: this is not an app hosted on aws ec2

**Question: How to disable 80 port on AWS for our case?**

Comment: no, it's not related to EC2 instance. Only S3 and CloudFront are used.

Comment: "Port 80 is the default setting when the origin is an Amazon S3 static website hosting endpoint, because Amazon S3 only supports port 80 for static website hosting endpoints..." from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDomainName , https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701167/592355

Answer (score 0):

You can update the viewer policy to disable the HTTP traffic.

Please follow this documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-s3-origin.html

Comment: AWS Docs say for HTTPS Only option: "If a viewer sends an HTTP request instead of an HTTPS request, CloudFront returns HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden) and does not return the object." An HTTP response of 403 means that port 80 was not disabled.